# Critique: How can I improve my logo design?

Tags: logo, critique

Can anyone give me some feedback on these logos -

[image]

I have been asked by a client to design a logo for a lingerie maker whose name in portuguese is "Virgem Lingerie", and means the same as virgin lingerie in English.

Please tell me which logos you think is best and worst and why.

How can I improve on the best and on the worst design?

Comment: I think when presenting them as comparisons of each other they should definitely all be shown at a common size. With all the different sizes there it's hard to make a fair comparison between tiny #8 and huge #4.

Comment: We need more data to appropriately critique. Who is the target audience? How is this company unique? What are the goals of the logo? In which context will the logo be used in? Etc.

Comment: 1, 6, and 7 are uninspiring. 2, 3 4, and 8 are too thin to hold up. 5 is the most viable, but then, 5 merely is 2 stock fonts and nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#3, #4, #5 and #8 work as logos. Others don't because they're just clipart-like image against type that we're very used with non-pro brands or self-branded local businesses.

### A bit more detail

#3 and #8 are actually a different version of the same logo. I like the brand symbol that's applicable on its own (clothing stitched labels) and serves as brand recognition symbol. The only problem I see with this symbol is thinness of lines. They will be very hard to produce on stitched labels which is likely something they'll do. Clothing companies usually have branded labels on their clothes anyway.

#4 and #5 would be usable for a speciality clothing shop, but not for a clothing production brand.

And let's say that others are simply not suitable for reasons of application and visual logo design. And if I may say those ladies don't really look like virgins. I'd say they look quite the opposite. :)

### A suggestion

And since circle is quite a bit used in logos (which is not a bad thing as it's very natural and pleasing) you could change that shape into stylized panties shape to make it more obvious when symbol would be presented without textual part.

That's not required of course. You could go with some other symbol, that relates to virginity. A butterfly being one for instance. But if you do go with a non-circular shape, it will become much harder to incorporate anything else long with it, because it's very hard to make two symbols to work as a single one.

In such case I'd rather opt for two logo variations:

- the full one where symbol is together with full worded text
- the symbol with VL text only - and use this one for labels

Unless symbol is super distinctive it couldn't be used on its own. At least not until this brand becomes widely recognised by target market.

I know it's a cliche with such brands but have you tried Bodoni or any other modern serif type with your design? I'm not convinced by your transitional font selection - hard to say which one it is due to small size but based on *g* it could be one of Robert Slimbach's designs - Minion or more likely Warnock.

And yes. Keep your colours. **Very suitable.**

Comment: Thank you, this is a very detailed review and i got what I needed to improve the designs. I'll post the new work soon for another round.

Answer (score 1):

One question to ask is: are you marketing to men or women?

If you are marketing to women, think on what has succeeded for the savvy number crunchers at places like Victoria's Secret:

[image]

But contrast that little emblematic thing with the broader picture of what they sell at a storefront.

[image]

*(I don't even recognize the logo.  Had to look it up.  I've been to lots of malls but never really noticed that used prominently or when I have been, uh, reviewing the catalogs for, um, graphic design research.)*

Things to notice about the VS choice:

- It's "Victoria's Secret", not "Victoria's Secret Lingerie".
- There is no clip art in the imagery; having a picture of a woman in lingerie, printed on lingerie... is kind of silly.  *(I'll offer that the Nike logo is also not of a shoe, which is then printed on a shoe.)*

To me the only keeper from the set given is #5 *(minus the "lingerie", in contexts where you are not legally required to tack that on for a trademark violation, but it's presumably a common word so you're safe as long as your mark is unique in your domain)*.

[image]

I'd always suggest thinking about context.  Is it going to be printed on a tag, is it going to be on a storefront?  For what and why are you making the mark?  How big are the tags, what is the aspect ratio?  What stitching colors are available?  Work within the medium...

Answer (score 0):

Those I liked:

- "Virgin-Lingerie.png" I like the concept, using two colours will fit with the rest of the Website Design and it's clear. But I can also be misunderstood as I know people with their dirty mind (irony).
- "Untitled copy.png" That's a great one especially for the simplistic concept that gives a "premium" effect to the brand, they can even use it for their products labels and so on, to be honest, I like simple logos like that.
- "VL circle fill copy 2.png" Like the previous one, the simplicity of the logo can give it a really great "premium" effect, it can also represent the brad (the circle only) that the consumer will recognize at first sight. That's the one I prefer.

The others :

- "Sexy-Lingerie-copy.png", "Sexy Lingerie copy2.png", "Sexy Lingerie copy3.png" As it's name is saying, it's "sexy", maybe it could drive to some dirty allusions, I think it's not very fitted for that use.
- "VL circle fill copy.png" Even if I liked the other one, this one is also great, but having the text in the bottom fits better I think.
- "Untitled.png" The font used here is a little "messy", I preferred the other font where it looks better for this subject.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really liking #8; subtle, sexy and feminine. I wouldn't change a thing. #3 is a close contender.

I don't think any of them are 'worst', or bad as such; I'm not a fan of the typefaces in #4, as they don't connote that subtlety that I might be searching for in a lingerie provider. I'm also not a fan of the logos with the girls in them - to me, this approach is too literal and overt, and risks cheapening the brand when the logo could connote femininity and sexuality through much less (just type and perhaps a circle, as you have done).

I would refer to the logo for the hotel chain, [Malmaison](http://www.james-oconnell.com/IMAGES/malmaison1.jpg) - dark, sexy and confident, with no extraneous detail, and tells its own story through its handwritten typeface.

I hope my comments help. :)